# How do I navigate namespaces in MonoTouch / Xamarin for iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

This is an example of something that I have experienced a couple of times when working with `MonoTouch`:

I find a code example on the internet giving an example on how to use the `NSUrl` class.  I try to add it to my code in `Xamarin Studio`.  It is simple, except I can't find which `using` statement to use.  I try to google, but no examples I find include the elusive `using` statement I am looking for.  I find the [the official Mac Developer Library NSUrl description](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but it does not tell me much (or perhaps it tells me too much).

In general, how do you go about finding which `using` statement to use in a case like this?  Is there a `Xamarin` documentation of this somewhere that I just can't find?  I'm not looking for the specific namespace from the example, but how to go about finding it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's an iOS API, it will always be

```
MonoTouch.<iOS Framework Name>
```

So if you found NSUrl, you should also be able to see that it is part of Apple's "Foundation" framework.

```
MonoTouch.Foundation
```

Of course, I would just recommend just letting the IDE figure it out for you.

> Right-click (on NSUrl) -> Resolve -> "using MonoTouch.Foundation"

Comment: Argh!  I can't understand how I missed right-click and Resolve!!  Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi, Erik!  I did not recognise that I had met you before.  Well, I have been working on my app.  A simple version of it is already out (just check my bio).  Thanks for your help again!